# Team Foundation services are not available from server - The remote name could not be resolved

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

We are working with Visual Studio 2010 and Team Foundation Server 2010. We did not have any problems for about half a year, but:

Since a couple of days we get the following error: Team Foundation services are not available from server (...) The remote name could not be resolved; (...)

[image: Team Foundation Server 2010 not available]

The problem occurs randomly (we are unable - yet - to pinpoint the conditions on which it occurs) and persists until we restart Visual Studio. The problem occurs about 8 times per day per developer.

Because we seem not to get past this problem and we cannot find anybody writing about this specific combination (the error and the 'remote name' part), I thought it wise to ask you guys about it ;) . Could anyone please help?

Comment: Does it happen at the same time for all the users?  Can you `ping` the server when it occurs?  Is there ever the case where you restart Visual Studio and this problem still occurs or does restarting always fix it immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of my co-workers and I had this problem as well. Out of about 25 developers, most never got this error. But three of us got it pretty consistently. The symptoms are identical, but we are using Visual Studio 2013 almost exclusively. In this version of Visual Studio, the error is preceded by the code: TF400324.

We found eventually that the three of us had all installed Productivity Power Tools 2013. And the developers that were not affected by this error had not installed it. Most had not heard of it. This used to be a very popular extension, so I have always installed it as I set up my system since about 2007. But apparently, in its modern incarnation in Visual Studio 2013, perhaps in combination with some quirk in our network or something, it can cause this problem. We have each uninstalled it, and have not gotten this error since. (It's been several months now.)

If you have this extension installed, you probably already know about it, because you probably installed it yourself. You probably started using it years ago, and it became a habit to add to each new installation. You will find that today, the default installation of Visual Studio actually includes most of its features already. To uninstall, go to Tools --> Extensions and Updates... Then click on Productivity Power Tools 2013, and click Uninstall.

Answer (score 6):

This is a client, server or infrastructure related problem on network level. The DNS entry for your TFS server cannot be resolved correctly at times for host dfz-vm223.

Suggestions for troubleshooting:

1. On some developer systems, replace the hostname dfz-vm223 by the ip-address of the TFS server. If the problem stop occuring there the DNS system is instable.
2. Setup a continuous ping stream (ping -t dfz-vmm223 from command window) and see if the host system is pingable in case you have TFS server problems.

Answer (score 5):

Just found out what the problem was: the problem is proxy related. When we disable our proxy, the problem is gone. It appears our proxy and TFS are troublesome together. If anyone experiences the same problem and you are working with a proxy server, I would suggest you try disabling the proxy too.

Comment: How did you disable your proxy?

Comment: I was having the same problem with no proxy on my machine. So I tried the opposite of what you suggest. I turned on Fiddler2, which acts as a proxy. It worked, no more libgit2 error.

Comment: Is this the correct way to disable proxy: http://www.speedguide.net/faq_in_q.php?qid=5 ?

Comment: For me it was still proxy related. Some how in my IE my proxy settings were overwritten by something else. I just checked settings of my colleague and do same settings on my local and it fixed for me. Note I m working in a complex infrastructure environment.

Answer (score 3):

#### I had the same problem, although I'm using VS2012 and a WAN connection to TFS.

I solved the problem by flushing the DNS cache.

To flush the DNS cache, start a command prompt with admin rights: `ipconfig /flushdns`

You need to do this in all the computers where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I had this problem sometimes when I ran Fiddler.

Sometimes Fiddler would crash or not clean up properly and the whole machine would get into some weird state where not even reboots were helping. The solution to it usually is to start Fiddler again, turn off any interceptors/collecting traffic and shut it down again.

Answer (score 2):

Hade the same issue. For whatever reason the windows DNS Client service on my PC wasn't running. Changing it from Disabled to Automatic solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for comments:

First off, as @kroonwijk stated, this is an infrastructure issue.  Your DNS queries are either timing out or the DNS server is not responding at certain times.

In a comment you mentioned a change over from regular machines to laptops for your entire dev team.  If I had to make a bet I'd say that the DNS configuration on the laptops is not the same as what you had on the other machines.

You need to take this up with your infrastructure people.  If you still have access to the older machines boot one of them up and compare the IP configuration.  If not, get them to fix the problem.  The DNS resolution problem could be any one of a number of factors.  For example, the new machines could be pointing to an incorrect DNS server that has network issues or their might be some incompatibility between how Win7 makes DNS requests and your DNS server.

Comment: In my situation it was a DNS conflict issue. I had a new server pointing to a different DNS server than the client accessing TFS through VS.

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced this problem and it doesn't always have to do with name resolution.

If you add an entry to your %systemroot%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file for your TFS server, it removes any dependance on your name resolution servers.

If you are still experiencing the problem, then it has to do with either visual studio or one of the VS Extensions that you are running.   There may be a memory leak somewhere.  Disable all your Extensions using the extension manager, restart VS, and see if you still experience the problem.

Comment: I agree. My command line tf.exe client works fine, but VS2012 shows the same error as the original poster here. I also have a hosts file entry, so I think my problem is related to VS and not DNS.